# Struts2 : possible to use dynamic method invocation and specify different validation rules for different methods?

Tags: java, dynamic, struts2, validation

I have in struts.xml :

```
    <action name="MyAction!*" class="my.Action" method="{1}">
        <result name="step1">step1.jsp</result>
        <result name="step2">step2.jsp</result>         
        <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Then my my.Action class has various methods that can be called by specifying the name in the URL, eg :

http://localhost:8080/MyApp/MyAction!method1.action

Now let's say that the fields `firstName` and `lastName` are mandatory in one method (e.g. first step of a registration) and not in the other methods.

If I make a general validation file like `MyAction-validation.xml`, it will make the fields required for all methods. If I make a specific validation like `MyAction-method1-validation.xml` it is not taken into account.

Is there a solution ?

Otherwise I'll have to map a different action in struts.xml for each method and not use dynamic method invocation - or do my validation manually.

Comment: Actually, this seems to be an open issue at the Struts2 JIRA : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-1967

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open bug in Struts 2's JIRA :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-1967

It's been open since june '07 so I doubt it will ever be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want to use the programmatic approach to validation. This is typically done with a `validate()` method, however you can create `validate` methods for specific action methods such as `validateStep1`, `validateStep2`, etc. Those will validate only the `step1` and `step2` methods. I'm not sure if there is an option available for using different XML files for different methods.

Also, you don't need the wildcard mapping in your action to use dynamic method invocation. Just use this:

```
<action name="MyAction" class="my.Action">
    <result name="step1">step1.jsp</result>
    <result name="step2">step2.jsp</result>         
    <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, nice to know the possibility to have different validation methods to programatically validate different methods, but I was specifically looking for a way to use different XML files. As for the mapping without wildcard, I don't doubt it will work but then what character will be the separator between action name and method name ? Is this a general struts configuration property ?

Comment: The default character separator for dynamic method invocation is an exclamation mark (!), so it would look the same for you.